# Como cambiar el orden de filas en plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

[image: Ejemplo 1]
Al momento de insertar agregue el dato de andrea y despues el de luisa en el ejemplo en ese orden me saldra al ejecutar un select

[image: Ejemplo 2]
Pero como cambio para que me salga asi, en el siguiente orden primero en dato de luisa y depues el de andrea? Osea sin hacen ningun tipo de condicion al ejecutar el select de la tabla

Answer (score 1):

Ejecutando el `select` con la condición `ORDER BY` y el nombre del campo puedes ordenar de forma ascendente y descendente,
Ejemplo - `Select * from tabla_ order by nombre desc`

Comment: Gracias por responder, y si osea eso lo se, pero yo lo que quiero es restructurar los datos de la tabla primero que me salga luisa y después andrea como en el segunda imagen al hacer un select sin condiciones.. Como select * from datos; que me salga en el orden que muestra la imagen

Comment: No puedes, si no pones el `order by` van a salir en el orden de inserción. La BBDD no puede adivinar cual es tu criterio de ordenación si no se lo indicas.

Comment: No hay alguna manera de usar alter table y alguna condición que modifique el orden como indico?

Comment: Hasta donde yo se no. ¿Cual es el problema de usar `ORDER BY' ?

Comment: No no hay problema en usar el order by, es para otro trabajo que tengo que realizar. gracias